# Transfereing Apps on Samsung

Tags: applications, samsung

I had some apps which were very useful on my old Samsung S3 and wanted to transfer them to my new s3. I went to applications manager and clicked on move to sd card. Not all the apps.can do this? Also now the sd card is in my new s3 I don't know how to access or install the apps that are supposed to be on my sd card.
Any help or ideas with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer apps like that. [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) only moves parts of the apps to free some "internal storage" – and no, not all apps support this (if they offer widgets or run services, they cannot be moved this way).

So as you never get the full `.apk` file moved-over this way, it obviously doesn't work for your purpose. What are your alternatives?

- You can install them from Playstore (or some other market place)
- You can restore them from a [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) taken
- You can use some "APK Catcher" (see my list of apps to [Backup your apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_132) for possible candidates)

Note however that if you want to transfer the apps' data along, you either need root – or have to use `adb backup` (see our [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for a starter).